# handling click on `ButtonGroup` in react-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

What is the right way to handle click on [ButtonGroup](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-groups)? 
Here is what I tried and it does not seem to work (the `key` values printed in `schemaTypeSelectionHandle` are not right).

```
<ButtonToolbar>
   <ButtonGroup onClick={this.schemaTypeSelectionHandle.bind(this)}>
     <Button eventKey='1'>Verb</Button>
     <Button eventKey='2'>Wiki Entity</Button>
   </ButtonGroup>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

with the following handle:

```
schemaTypeSelectionHandle(key) {
    console.log('key: ');
    console.log(key);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `data-key` attribute to buttons:

```
<ButtonToolbar>
  <ButtonGroup onClick={this.schemaTypeSelectionHandle.bind(this)}>
    <Button data-key='1'>Verb</Button>
    <Button data-key='2'>Wiki Entity</Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

And use `event.target` to get the element:

```
schemaTypeSelectionHandle(event) {
  // console.log('key: ', $(event.target).data('key'));
  console.log('key: ', event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-key').value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `value` attribute to buttons:

```
<ButtonToolbar>
  <ButtonGroup onClick={this.schemaTypeSelectionHandle.bind(this)}>
    <Button value='1'>Verb</Button>
    <Button value='2'>Wiki Entity</Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

And use `event.target.value` to get the value:

```
schemaTypeSelectionHandle(event) {
  // console.log('key: ', $(event.target).data('key'));
  console.log('key: ', event.target.value);
}
```